Specifying parameter type in ROS2 XML launch file
I am trying to declare two string parameters vid and pid for a serial communication node in ROS2. However, when I use the following launch file to pass my parameters:
<launch>
  <node pkg="serial" exec="serial">
    <param name="vid" type="str" value="0483"/>
    <param name="pid" type="str" value="5740"/>
  </node>
</launch>

I got the following error:
[serial-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rclcpp::exceptions::InvalidParameterTypeException'
[serial-1]   what():  parameter 'vid' has invalid type: Wrong parameter type, parameter {vid} is of type {string}, setting it to {double} is not allowed.

It seems like my type specification was never respected by roslaunch.
According to the official documentation it seems like ROS2 removed support for explicit type declaration. I want to understand the rationale behind this change and find out possible alternative approaches (without moving away from xml format).

Update: Add C++ source code for reproducibility
class SerialNode: public rclcpp::Node {
  SerialNode(): Node("serial") {
    declare_parameter<std::string>("pid", "");
    declare_parameter<std::string>("vid", "");
    declare_parameter<int>("baud", 115200);
    const auto vid = get_parameter("vid").as_string();
    const auto pid = get_parameter("pid").as_string();
    const auto baud = get_parameter("baud").as_int();
  }
  /* irrelevant code omitted ... */
}


Update:

The python version of launch file also produces identical error.
I added a letter x in front of my values (i.e. x0483 and x5740 instead of 0483 and 5740), then the parameters are successfully passed as strings. I think this is a very strong proof that my code is not causing this error.

[serial-1] No serial port found for device x0483:x5740


Can you update your launch file like this? I think there is a problem on your XML file.
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch_ros.actions import Node

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        Node(
            package='serial',  
            executable='serial',
            name='serial',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[
                {'vid': 0x0483},  # 'vid' parameter
                {'pid': 0x5740},  # 'pid' parameter
            ]
        ),
    ])


I've checked it multiple times. I've updated my question and added my C++ code.

Here is the funny part: roslaunch interprets 0483 as "double" just because of the preceding 0. It treats 5740 as "int", and in case vid or pid contains a letter a - f (since they are hex strings) roslaunch would treat them as string instead. I feel totally out of control of its funny behavior.

Can you use launch.py instead of launch.xml? I have updated my reply on code, please check it.

It turned out to throw the same error: what():  parameter 'vid' has invalid type: Wrong parameter type, parameter {vid} is of type {string}, setting it to {double} is not allowed.. I commented out these lines in the python launch file so it did not throw this error previously.

Also, as I stated in the original post, I would really prefer to stick to xml launch files because I need to parse them with my own script.

Okay, you are right. Can you use these parameters on hex format? I have updated my reply again. Please try it.

I think it will work now. I mean I hope :)

Yeah I am aware of this solution, but I think roslaunch should be better than this. The fix is not elegant and induces unnecessary burden on developers. Imagine a system which previously worked fine got crashed just because a string parameter being changed to only digits...

Yes, I understand. This definition may work with these parameters on ROS1. If you want we can craete issue about this on rclcpp github repo. I am happy that you have a solution (:

I've opened an issue at ros2/launch, not sure if it's the correct location.

By the way, thank you @furkansariyildiz so much for your time and involvement!

I think it is correct repo for this issue. I wish I could help more. Enjoy your work :)
